# C++ Insert into MySQl database

Tags: c++, mysql

I have one application in c++ and i'm using the C++ Mysql Connector (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/)

I need to save some logs inside one table.Depending on the times I may have large amounts of data on the order of thousands (for example, 80,000).

I already implement a function that iterate my `std::vector<std::string>` and save the `std::string` to my database.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines = explode(filedata, '\n');
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
   std::vector<std::string> elements = explode(lines[i], ';');
   ui64 timestamp = strtol(elements.at(0).c_str(), 0, 10);
   std::string pointId = elements.at(6);
   std::string pointName = elements.at(5);
   std::string data = elements.at(3);

   database->SetLogs(timestamp, pointId, pointName, data);
}
```

The logs come from csv file, i save all fields to my vector. After this i parse the vector (with explode) and get only the fields that i need to save.

But i have a problem. If i have e.g 80,000 i'm calling my function to save in database 80,000. It works and save correctly all data but it takes a lot of time.

Exists some way to save all data only calling one time the function to save without calling e.g 80,000 and thus optimize the time?

EDIT 1

I change the insert code to this:

```
std::string insertLog = "INSERT INTO Logs (timestamp,pointId,pointName,data) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

   pstmt->setString(1, timestampString); 
   pstmt->setString(2, pointId);
   pstmt->setString(3, pointName);
   pstmt->setString(4, data);
   pstmt->executeUpdate();
```

Comment: If the code you have works correctly, and you only want to improve performance: [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better place to ask such questions.

Comment: maybe you are looking for builk insertion https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the code to do bulk inserts, rather than insert one row at a time.

I would recommend doing it by generating an insert statement as a string and passing the string to `mysqlpp::Query`. I expect you can use a prepared statement to do bulk inserts in a similar way.

If you do an insert statement for each row (which I assume the case here using `explode()`), I think there's a lot more traffic between the client and the server, which must slow things down.

**EDIT**

I doubt the function `explode()` for increasing the execution time as you are accessing the file twice when you call explode twice. It would be nice if you can produce the code for explode().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see my original question, i add a "Edit 1". I think now its more fast with the new code but we spend 4min to save 55748 registers in database... its much no?

Comment: Can you please tell the previous matrix? The time required previously?

Comment: 4 mins can still be optimised if you improve your logic to reduce the number of file access.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. In first version (orignal question) to save 56000 registers it spends 8minutes.. in the second version (EDIT 1) it spends 4minutes... but it's still too long, is not it?

Comment: My code works like this: I go to the csv file, load all logs and save in my vector.. in the function to insert in database, i iterate the vector and for each position i do the code that i put in EDIT 1

Comment: I don't find any further optimization for Database insertion as batch insertion is the best way to insert as it opens a single connection to the database. I feel you need to optimize the `explode()` function.